# getDisplayMetrics().density vs dp

Tags: android, margin

Do these two do the same in terms of mathematics? Do they produce the same result?

Java:

```
pixel=10;
margin=px * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
layout_param.topMargin=margin;
```

XML:

`android:layout_marginTop="10dp"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are, the density inside getDisplayMetrics() is the one used for dip unit following the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density):

> public float density
>
> Added in API level 1 The logical density of the display. This is a
>   scaling factor for the Density Independent Pixel unit, where one DIP
>   is one pixel on an approximately 160 dpi screen (for example a
>   240x320, 1.5"x2" screen), providing the baseline of the system's
>   display. Thus on a 160dpi screen this density value will be 1; on a
>   120 dpi screen it would be .75; etc.
>
> This value does not exactly follow the real screen size (as given by
>   xdpi and ydpi, but rather is used to scale the size of the overall UI
>   in steps based on gross changes in the display dpi. For example, a
>   240x320 screen will have a density of 1 even if its width is 1.8",
>   1.3", etc. However, if the screen resolution is increased to 320x480 but the screen size remained 1.5"x2" then the density would be
>   increased (probably to 1.5).